# I have a generic "checkType" function with args as parameter and then how to be able to return the value type according to attached parameters

Tags: kotlin, parameters

Examples are as follows:
*

- input: checkType(10)
- output: "Yes! it's Integer"
- 
- Here are some mandatory value types.
- • Integer
- • Strings
- • Boolean
- • Double
- • List
- • Map<String, String>
- 

fun  checkType(args: T): String {
return ""
}

fun main() {
println(
"""
'[10, 9, 8 , 6]' is List? ${checkType(listOf(10, 9, 8, 6))}
'Kotlin' is String? ${checkType("Kotlin")}
'True' is Boolean? ${checkType(true)}
'10.01' is List? ${checkType(10.01)}
""".trimIndent()
)
}

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and why.

Comment: Please format the code properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting (and maybe check out other question to see how they look)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear, but I'll do my best to set you on the right track. I suggest you make it clearer and [reformat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it.

You can use [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) to make use of the type inside the function, like so:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> checkType(value: Any): Boolean = values is T
```

To check if a value has a certain type, call it like this:

```kotlin
checkType<String>("test")
checkType<Int>("test)
```

They will return a boolean value and you can then turn them into the desired string using an `if/else` expression:

```kotlin
val text = "Is 10 a string? " + if (checkType<String>(10)) "Yes it is!" else "No, it is not."
```