# Generic "checkType" function with args as parameter, but I don't know how to make it able to the value type according to attached parameters

Tags: kotlin

Example

> input: checkType(10)

> output: "Yes! it's Integer"

Here are some mandatory value types:

- Integer
- String
- Boolean
- Double
- List
- Map<String, String>

```
fun <T> checkType(args: T): String {
    return ""
}

fun main() {
    println(
        """
        '[10, 9, 8 , 6]' is List? ${checkType(listOf(10, 9, 8, 6))}
        'This is Koltin' is String? ${checkType("This is Kotlin")}
        'True' is Boolean? ${checkType(true)}
        '10.01' is List? ${checkType(10.01)}
    """.trimIndent()
    )
}
```

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811287/i-have-a-generic-checktype-function-with-args-as-parameter-and-then-how-to-be a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <T> checkType(args: T): String {
when(args){
    is Int-> return "Yes! it's Integer"
    is String-> return "Yes! it's String"
    is Boolean-> return "Yes! it's boolean"
    is Double-> return "Yes! it's Double"
    is List<*>-> return "Yes! it's List"
    is Map<*, *>-> return "Yes! it's Map"
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.